# Date conversion doesn't work in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, date-conversion

I am trying to query against the columns SOE (datetime field) and Answer (varchar field) from a table where NOT ALL Answer values are dates but some of them are. If I remove the datediff from the 'where' clause, I'm able to run the query just fine. But on including it, it errors out saying that **'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'**.

For context, I'm using SQL Server 2014.

This is what my query looks like:

```
select ID, 
       convert(datetime, Answer, 121) as Answer, 
       datediff(dd,convert(datetime, 
       Answer, 121), SOE) as Days
from table
where Type in (1) and SOE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-03-31'
      and FormLocation = 'M1005_INP_DISCHARGE_DT'
      and PayorType = 'Medicare'
      and Answer <> ' '
      datediff(dd, convert(datetime, Answer, 121), SOE) <= 5
```

Any tips on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Fix your data so that you don't have a mix of dates and non-dates in a column where you need to query for dates. If you have bad data, expect to have problems using it.

Comment: What are the datatypes involved?

Comment: could your problem be as simple as the fact that you forgot to put "AND" before datediff?

Comment: It's not just the `WHERE` clause. Date conversion doesn't work anywhere if it isn't a date data type. Seriously consider converting to the correct data type in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Before doing the conversion to datetime make sure the data in the "Answer" field can be converted to date. Try this...

`and ((isdate(Answer) = 1) and (datediff(dd, convert(datetime, Answer, 121), SOE) <= 5))`

Answer (score 1):

Since 2012 you can use [`try_convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
...
datediff(dd, try_convert(datetime, Answer, 121), SOE) <= 5
...
```

`try_convert()` returns `NULL` if the conversion doesn't succeed. And so does `datediff()` then. So you might want to handle that case some way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` you can save yourself some repetitive code:

```
select ID, 
       answer_datetime as Answer, 
       datediff(day, answer_datetime, SOE) as Days
from table t cross apply
     (values (try_convert(datetime, Answer, 121))) v(answer_datetime)
where Type in (1) and
      SOE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-03-31' and
      FormLocation = 'M1005_INP_DISCHARGE_DT' and
      PayorType = 'Medicare' and
      Answer <> ' ' and
      datediff(day, answer_datetime, SOE) <= 5;
```

But you should really fix the data definitions so date/times are stored using the correct type.

Comment: That's really helpful but since the way we have the table set up doesn't allow me to separate the date answers into a different table. I was able to make it work using a temp table though. Thank you!